# Migrate AWS Glue Job to EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue

i'm currently using some glue jobs for minimum transformations and sending info from S3/Athena tables to Redshift, now we don't process a lot of data so glue is expensive, slow and difficult to tune for this volume of data.
I couldn't find how to start in EC2 to make the code migration, credentials, dependencies.

Maybe I can call a lambda to process it in my EC2 instance? Can I run spark on 1 node and then scale to a cluster in the future? should I migrate Glue Job to python (not pyspark)?

I found EMR will be expensive too for this volume, the ideal is start with minumum
Don't need the full solution, just pointing in the right direction so I can start trying this.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here are few suggetions for your requiremnt

1. Serverless frameworks like Glue and lambda is more suitable rather than persisted EMR or EC2
2. **AWS Lambda:** You can consider using lambda with python modules, if your volume of data is less  and transformations are minimal.
3. AWS Glue with Python not spark - It's also a cost effective solution.
4. AWS Ec2 - Going for EC2 legacy approach and costly.

Comment: thank you! I looked prices of 2 node EMR cluster and it seems ok, maybe I can move there

Comment: is it persisted EMR or Transient EMR.